# Makefile and CImg

Tags: makefile

I am having trouble developing a makefile for a code using the CImg library. I have 3 files:

mainProgram.cpp

program.cpp

program.h

CImg.h // CImg library

In the mainProgram.cpp

```
#include "program.h"
```

In the program.cpp

```
#include "program.h"
```

In the program.h

```
#ifndef PROGRAM_H
#define PROGRAM_H
#include "CImg.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;
```

I am using a MAC and it suggested to compile it using: g++ -o snake  mainSnake.cpp -O2 -lm -lpthread -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11

But, I am having difficulty communicating this to a makefile. Can anyone assist me?

Comment: Did you try writing the makefile? Post the makefile you have written, then if any error is coming then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest make file would be

```
all:mainProgram.cpp program.cpp program.h
    g++ -o snake mainSnake.cpp -O2 -lm -lpthread -I/usr/X11R6/include -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lm -lpthread -lX11
```

If you read some basics of makefile writing then you can first create the object files then create the final `snake` executable

May be [this](http://sagarsakre.blogspot.com/2012/09/understanding-makefile-for-beginners.html) would help you get started with. The similar example is given but in `c`.